# How to publish CVC (Custom Visualization Component) on JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I've worked hard for building my own CVC (a choropleth map based on Rapaehl Map) but now I'm facing two big problems when I try to publish my project.

1) The CVC seems not working properly with Sub Dataset: there is the possibility to select one of report's subdatasets but then it doesn't recognize the fields.

2) When I try to publish my CVC on JasperReports Sever (5.5.0), the server returns me this error:

```
com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSExceptionWrapper:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 519; columnNumber: 192;
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'cvc:customvisualization'. One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":component}' is expected.
```

Answer (score 0):

The custom Visualization Feature is not supported by Jasper 5.5 version it is available only from Jasper version 5.6 and it is completely changed since version 6.1 and above.